# Calculate lists in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

I was wondering if it was possible to calculate a list, for example this one

```
calculation = [1, "+", 2, "*", 15]
```

so it returns 31.

Comment: Where does that list come from? Is it user input? Or is it generated by your own code?

Comment: The list is User input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `eval` ever. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Instead you can refer some other library like [asteval](http://newville.github.io/asteval/installation.html)

```
from asteval import Interpreter
aeval = Interpreter()
calculation = [1, "+", 2, "*", 15]
aeval.eval(''.join(map(str, calculation)))
```

Comment: Worked great for me, was wondering if there was a alternative to eval. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could take a look at a binary expression tree.

[binary expression tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree)

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
eval(' '.join(map(str, calculation)), {}, {})
```

The inner `join` (no pun intended) builds a single string which is valid Python code, then you simply `eval()` it.

The two `{}`s are optional, they make it so the code runs without access to the surrounding global and local variables.

Answer (score 0):

`eval` can be used for evaluating an expression (which is in the form of a string) in python.

Desired output can be obtained as below

```
eval(''.join([str(x) for x in calculation]))
```